# How to return a message to HTTP request in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, rest, jpa, error-handling

I am creating an API to simulate a vending machine and I'm using Spring, JPA and MySQL. I have an endpoint for a POST request that allows for new user creation by entering the user's details into a table called `users`. I have a check to see if the username already exists in the table and if it does, I want to return a message that says the creation of a new user was unsuccessful because that username is already in use. If the user name is not in the table, I want to return the `User` object.

How do I return this error message? From what I have found so far, suggestions include the usage of ResponseEntity or creating a custom exception handler which all seemed overly complicated for something that I feel is quite straightforward. Is there an easier way to do this?

So this is what I want the response to look like when a new user has been created successfully (which I have currently managed to get working successfully):

```
{
    "username": "user",
    "password": "password",
    "role": "BUYER",
    "deposit": 0.0,
    "id": 12
}
```

And if it fails, I want it to return something that looks along the lines of:

```
Error: username already in use.
```

or:

```
{
  "error" : "Username already in use"
}
```

User object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int userId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "username", unique = true)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "role")
    private Role role;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "deposit")
    private BigDecimal deposit;

    public User() {}

    public User(String username, String password, Role role, BigDecimal deposit)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
        this.deposit = deposit;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return userId;
    }

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Role getRole()
    {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role)
    {
        this.role = Role.valueOf(role);
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public BigDecimal getDeposit()
    {
        return deposit;
    }

    public void setDeposit(BigDecimal deposit)
    {
        this.deposit = deposit;
    }
}
```

Method in the controller that is being called:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/create-user", consumes = {"application/json"})
    public User createUser(@RequestBody User user)
    {
        return userService.createUser(user);
    }
```

createUser method in UserService:

```
    public User createUser(User user)
    {
//        if(userRepository.userExists(user.getUsername()) == 0)
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

`UserRepository` is an interface that extends `JpaRepository`.

If I have missed some information or have worded the question incorrectly, please let me know and I'll update accordingly.

Comment: Please [edit] the post and share the (relevant) code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved in multiple ways.

1. You can use JpaRepository's `existsById()` or similar "exists" methods. This would return a boolean. If it's true, that is if the entry already exists for a given id, you can send an error response. Otherwise, new user object. For that, you can have a model class something like `UserOrError` which will either hold a user object or an error string at a time. Use `@JsonView` annotation from Jackson library to show/ hide the fields. [Read more](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation)
2. Based on the result of the above "exists" method, wrap it with `ResponseEntity<T>`. The return type of your controller method should be `ResponseEntity<T>`. Here's the [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html). The advantage of this method is that you can send different HTTP status codes
3. Throw a custom `RuntimeException` in your service layer and use Spring's exception handling like the `RestControllerAdvice` annotation

Comment: For the first option, when you say the class will hold either a user object or an error string, do you mean the class will have both but the user object will be null if there's an error message? Or is there actually a way to configure a class such that it contains one type or another?

Comment: @mdaabis yes. The class is same for both. You can use `@JsonView` annotation from Jackson library to show/ hide fields based on scenarios. (Updated the same in the answer)